# Psalm-like indentation

Tags: macros, indentation, automation

I'm trying to make a kind of breviary containing psalms indented like e.g. [here](http://universalis.com/lauds.htm)
What I managed so far is indenting by hand every two other verses.
It goes like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent O God, you are my God, for you I long; *\\
for you my soul is thirsting.\\
\indent My body pines for you *\\
\indent like a dry, weary land without water.\\
So I gaze on you in the sanctuary *\\
to see your strength and your glory.\\
\indent For your love is better than life, *\\
\indent my lips will speak your praise.\\
So I will bless you all my life, *\\
in your name I will lift up my hands.\\
\indent My soul shall be filled as with a banquet, *\\
\indent my mouth shall praise you with joy.\\
On my bed I remember you. *\\
On you I muse through the night\\
\indent for you have been my help; *\\
\indent in the shadow of your wings I rejoice.\\
My soul clings to you; *\\
your right hand holds me fast.\\
\indent Glory to the Father, and to the Son, *\\
\indent and to the Holy Spirit:\\
as it was in the beginning, is now, *\\
and will be for ever. Amen.

\end{document}
```

It looks fine but takes a lot of nonsense work.
Does anyone know how to automatize the job?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: look for `\hangindent` but do you intend those `*` to be typeset?(just checking)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not really and answer, but rather a suggestion.  Keep your content separate from layout. You don't want *that* particular line to be indented, you want the first 2 out of 4 lines to be indented (e.g. what happen if you typesetted Ps. 118(9) and you realize you forgot line 3 and 4?!). You could also have a look at [Package to typeset Poems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160560/64454) (even if does not directly solve the indentation issue).

Comment: You could also adapt solutions suggested in [Formatting verse: How to change indent for all even lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188336/64454)

Comment: Instead of modifying your existing query to create what is, in essence, an entirely new and separate query, you should have posted a new query, in which you would focus attention on just the new part.

Comment: Right, here is [the new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360270/127990)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}


\begingroup
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\def\par{\ifvmode\noindent\else\endgraf\fi}
\obeylines


O God, you are my God, for you I long; *

for you my soul is thirsting.
My body pines for you *
like a dry, weary land without water.

So I gaze on you in the sanctuary *

to see your strength and your glory.
For your love is better than life, *
my lips will speak your praise.

So I will bless you all my life, *

in your name I will lift up my hands.
My soul shall be filled as with a banquet, *
my mouth shall praise you with joy.

On my bed I remember you. *

On you I muse through the night
for you have been my help; *
in the shadow of your wings I rejoice.

My soul clings to you; *

your right hand holds me fast.
Glory to the Father, and to the Son, *
and to the Holy Spirit:

as it was in the beginning, is now, *

and will be for ever. Amen.

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how it works? Even if the 'trick' is only two commands, I'm hardly understanding its functioning!

Comment: @ebo `\obeylines` makes the end of line an active character with definition `\par` which means that every line is a paragraph (so you can not use `\hangindent`) however you can indent everything (`leftskip` then detect in the local definition of `\par` that you had a blank line and if so back-space up to remove the `\leftskip` indentation.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki why?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was first confused with the "`1/blank/2-3-4/blank`" scheme for clustering lines. But thanks to your explanations I got it. It should be understood as: "*if a line of text has a blank line above, then it's not indented*" and thus be read as "`blank-1/blank-2/3/4`".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant to say essentially what ego asked you for: it is helpful to have some explanation of the code. It's great that you provided it in a comment. For future viewers of this answer, though, it might be nice to add your explanations to the answer itself.

Comment: Very neat indeed. It is also possible to put \bfseries and \normafont in the appropriate places in the redefinition of \par so that the indented bits are in bold while the unindented bits are not. And, an added benefit, with a minimum of markup.

Comment: The liturgical requirements that I had to fulfill required roman type for odd lines and bold for the even. In any event, a very neat (in all senses) solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for help. It'll make my work a lot easier now :)

Comment: While using the code I found that treating every line as a separate paragraph gives new vertical spaces between the lines. Also `\hspace*{-\leftskip}` was doubling horizontal space between indented and unindented verses. I also created a new environment just to make things easier for myself.
What I'm left with is 
`\newenvironment{psalm}{
 \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
 \def\par{\ifvmode\noindent\else\endgraf\fi}
 \obeylines
 
}{}`

Comment: @Precluch oh sorry Yes I see what you mean, yes you need to set parskip to 0 if it is not 0 in your real document. the hspace was remains from an earlier try it is nonsense, i'll update, sorry:-)

Comment: @DavieCarlisle I'm struggling with the comment while you manage to answer :) I'm glad we both know now what should it be and that I have my macro. Thank you

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Interesting! What about when any line flows to the next line? Typically in this case, the indent of the flowed line is set to 2 or 3 times `\parindent` (I end up using a list environment to set psalms, but your set-up is much simpler!)

Comment: This works to get the extra hanging indent: `\def\par{\ifvmode\noindent\else\endgraf\fi\hangindent=3\parindent\hangafter=1}`

Comment: @DavidPurton that doesn't look quite right (the unindented lines won't get a hang indent in that case which the OP wanted.) Note in my version above you can set the two hang indent values to different values if you want the ones that start indented to hang indent more. No time now, I'll pass by later today see if any more comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`scripture`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scripture) package. Internally, this uses the same technique as David's answer, but with extra features and configuration options.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scripture}
\scripturesetup{
  poetry/leftmargin=0pt
}
\begin{document}
\begin{scripture}
  \begin{poetry}
    O God, you are my God, for you I long; *

    for you my soul is thirsting.
    My body pines for you *
    like a dry, weary land without water.

    So I gaze on you in the sanctuary *

    to see your strength and your glory.
    For your love is better than life, *
    my lips will speak your praise.

    So I will bless you all my life, *

    in your name I will lift up my hands.
    My soul shall be filled as with a banquet, *
    my mouth shall praise you with joy.

    On my bed I remember you. *

    On you I muse through the night
    for you have been my help; *
    in the shadow of your wings I rejoice.

    My soul clings to you; *

    your right hand holds me fast.
    Glory to the Father, and to the Son, *
    and to the Holy Spirit:

    as it was in the beginning, is now, *

    and will be for ever. Amen.
  \end{poetry}
\end{scripture}
\end{document}
```