# Align last word of paragraph to the right and \obeylines

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using code from *The TeXBook* to align some text to the right of the last line of the paragraph or to the of the next line if there isn't room on the last line of the paragraph. (See chapter 14, page 106 and implementation below.)

It works well, except there are situations when I have a section of text in an environment using `\obeylines`. This messes things up, since `\obeylines` inserts a paragraph break at the end of each line including the last line and the text to be aligned to the right always appears on a line by itself even if there is space for it on the previous line.

I can work around this by suppressing the paragraph break on the last line of the `\obeylines` section with a `%` on the end of the line.

But I'm after an automatic way that doesn't require me to do this.

Here's a MWE to play with.

The `zzsection` and `olsection` environments simulate environments I use in my document structure. I'd like to just modify code in these two environments, not the text within the environments. The `olsection` may occur with ordinary text above or below it. I.e., the only case that needs to be worked around is when a `zzsection` finishes with an `olsection` environment. *Filler text* is of arbitrary length and content. Hopefully that makes sense…

In this example, the third paragraph is the one that needs correcting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\zz}{%
  {\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
   \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\textbf{Filler text}%
   \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}

\newenvironment{zzsection}{}{\zz}
\newenvironment{olsection}{\obeylines}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{zzsection}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{zzsection}

\begin{zzsection}
  \lipsum[5]
\end{zzsection}

\begin{zzsection}
  \begin{olsection}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{olsection}
\end{zzsection}

\begin{zzsection}
  \begin{olsection}
    \lipsum[5]
  \end{olsection}
\end{zzsection}

\end{document}
```

---

### Update

Henri Menke's code is almost perfect for me.

My actual document has a `\leftskip 1cm` inside the `olsection` environment. This isn't taken into account for the last line with his answer. i.e., this fails:

```
\begin{zzsection}
  \begin{olsection}
    \leftskip 1cm
    Some text.
    Some text.
    Some text.
  \end{olsection}
\end{zzsection}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make obeylines look ahead for `\end`.

If there may be multiple blank lines before the `\end` you might need to skip these recursively.  This is quite slow because it absorbs tokens one by one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\zz}{%
  {\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
   \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\textbf{Filler text}%
   \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}

% Loosely adapted from ConTeXt
%
% Two stage indirection via \obeylineshandler is such that we can change
% \obeyedline at some later stage.
\newcommand*\obeyedline{\par}
\newcommand*\obeylineshandler{\obeyedline}
{\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with %
  \protected\gdef\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M\active \let^^M\obeylineshandler}%
  \global\let^^M\obeylineshandler} % this is in case ^^M appears in a \write

% Look ahead for \end and skip any ^^M on the way there
\makeatletter
{\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with %
\gdef\obeylineend{%
    \@ifnextchar\end{}{%
        \@ifnextchar^^M{%
            \expandafter\obeylineend\@gobble}{\par}}}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{zzsection}{}{\zz}
\newenvironment{olsection}{\let\obeyedline\obeylineend\obeylines}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{zzsection}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{zzsection}

\begin{zzsection}
  \lipsum[5]
\end{zzsection}

\begin{zzsection}
  \begin{olsection}
    \lipsum[1]

  \end{olsection}
\end{zzsection}

\begin{zzsection}
  \begin{olsection}
    \lipsum[5]
  \end{olsection}
\end{zzsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooh! This looks very promising. It doesn't quite work in my actual document, but I may be able to fix that.

Comment: @DavidPurton I can guess your problem is with multiple blank lines before the `\end`.  See my updated answer for that.

Comment: I have a `\leftskip 1cm` in my `olsection` environment. This seems to be ignored on the last line.

Comment: Speed isn't a concern. These documents are short and this structure only appears rarely.

Comment: Your initial `\obeylineend` macro gives better results in my actual code. i may need to ask a new question with a little more detail of what actually is in the `olsection` environment. (It's quite similar to the `psalm` environment at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360322/87678)

Comment: Regarding the `\leftskip`, you have to move it outside of the `olsection` environment.  The `\leftskip` is only applied when `\par` is encountered but that is outside of the group defined by `olsection` for the last line of text.  Maybe you could smuggle the `\leftskip` out using some `\aftergroup` trickery but that might have other unexpected side-effects and is of course incomplete, because the same situation would apply to other paragraph parameters like `\rightskip` or `\baselineskip`, etc.

Comment: I don't see how it makes a difference putting it outside the `olsection`? The right aligned text is attached to the `zzsection`, so if there's no extra text after the `olsection`, the indent is returned to `0pt` and is still wrong. I have now got a working implementation involving an `\everypar{}`, a boolean check, and an `\aftergroup`, but it's not pretty. It requires a blank line after the `olsection`, so if I don't want a new paragraph I need to insert `\noindent`. I can live with that. I might still follow up with another question. (Still only your original `\futurelet` code works.)

Comment: @DavidPurton I don't know exactly what's going on in your case, but my previous comment was about a setup like this: http://dpaste.com/0190C27 (expires in 10 days)

Comment: Yes, but that's no good, because the `\leftskip` has to return to 0pt after the `olsection` since sometimes (often actually) there is more text between `\end{olsection}` and the `\end{zzsection}`. Don't worry for now. I'll think about a better defined follow-up question. Already what you've done has helped.